# Shift geometric object along horizontal axis with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use ggplot to plot three curves, each made with `stat_function` and with its own parameters.
This is done with the code below:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 25)), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) plogis(x, location = 5, scale = 2), colour = "red") +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) plogis(x, location = 9, scale = 3), colour = "blue") +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) plogis(x, location = 9, scale = 4), colour = "green")
```

which gives the figure below:

[image]

What I want to achieve is to shift the blue and green curves, exactly as they are, to the right along the horizontal axis (each by an arbitrary amount).

I don't know of an explicit way to do it in ggplot, so I tried to specify a different frame for the second and third geometric objects, as below:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 25)), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) plogis(x, location = 5, scale = 2), colour = "red") +
  stat_function(data = data.frame(x = c(3, 28)), fun = function(x) plogis(x, location = 9, scale = 3), colour = "blue") +
  stat_function(data = data.frame(x = c(5, 30)), fun = function(x) plogis(x, location = 9, scale = 4), colour = "green")
```

But the resulting image is the same as the one above.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is almost correct, but you need to subtract the same constant within the function itself, so that the y-values still correspond.

```
c1 <- 4
c2 <- 4
p2 <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 25)), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) plogis(x, location = 5, scale = 2), colour = "red") +
  stat_function(data = data.frame(x = c(0+c1, 25+c1)),
                fun = function(x) plogis(x - c1, location = 9, scale = 3), colour = "blue") +
  stat_function(data = data.frame(x = c(0+c2, 25+c2)),
                fun = function(x) plogis(x - c2, location = 9, scale = 4), colour = "green")


p2
```

[image]

PS: In the answer, I have added the constants also to the data.frame itself, so that the shift is shown (you can remove them from the df in case you want you want only the original x-range shown).